# How to accept iter and non-iter return types in Python

Tags: python, swig

Forgive me if this has been asked before. I can't seem to filter out all the other questions about failed `iter()` overrides.

I'm using the https://github.com/mz-automation/libiec61850 third party library, which uses SWIG to interface with it's C code. For some reason SWIG is returning different things if there is an error.

```
>>> iec61850.IedConnection_getFileDirectory(mms._mms_con, "/SETTINGS")  
[<iec61850.sLinkedList; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'LinkedList' at 0x03063C20> >, 0]
>>> iec61850.IedConnection_getFileDirectory(mms._mms_con, "/FAKE")     
22  
>>>
```

How am I suppose to accept both scenarios? The only thing I can think of is try/except TypeError, but I can't seem to get the error condition in that case. Is there a way to fix the SWIG translation?

From iec61850_client.h:

```
LIB61850_API LinkedList /*<FileDirectoryEntry>*/
IedConnection_getFileDirectory(IedConnection self, IedClientError* error, const char* directoryName);
```

Using the SWIG i file from:

https://github.com/mz-automation/libiec61850/blob/v1.4/pyiec61850/iec61850.i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague helped me out with this one. I didn't realize you could set the list to a single object. Duh. The code below easily handles both conditions.

```
try:
    [device_list, ied_error] = ret_object
except TypeError:
    # SWIG returns just an int on some failures.
    ied_error = ret_object
```

For future reference, this is a good reason to use a single return type...

Comment: 1. you don't need the square brackets.   2. It would be a `ValueError` not a `TypeError`...

Comment: Without the square brackets is exactly the same and I'm getting a TypeError. Are you getting a ValueError with this code?

Comment: Yes, unpacking 1 object into 2 names will always be `ValueError`.  If you're seeing `TypeError` I think it must be coming from somewhere else (the traceback will say where exactly).